# Set the inital number of empty values for a cck multi-value field

Tags: 6, entities

I have CCK fields that can hold multiple values, I would like some of them to default to showing say 5 values initially.

I'm not looking for any validation that all 5 values are used however.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the fields to hold a max of 5 values or unlimited but only showing 5 input fields initially?

Comment: unlimited but 5 initially :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this without altering the module code of CCK.

There have been a few patches created that will allow you to set the number of fields initially shown *and* let you choose how many more to add when click the "Add another" button. However, this feature is not available in the core of Drupal 7 which may be a problem if you choose to upgrade.

Patch created for CCK 2: http://drupal.org/node/530828#comment-3397196

Patch created for CCK 3: http://drupal.org/node/841914#comment-3209072